# Different meanings of "fare", how to distinguish it in following sentence which seems vague even with considering context

Tags: meaning

I couldn't find any complete answer to my 2 questions here in the forum. I know based on context the verb "fare" can have 3 different meanings: 1 - fare in modo che 2 - permettere 3 -lasciare. So, first I want to know in addition to being based on context, is there any trick to distinguish each usage of these three?

Secondly, nevertheless I tried to use each one of these three meaning in following sentence, but I couldn't grasp the meaning:

> Se prima i nonni facevano solo i nonni, oggi fanno i nonni e i genitori.

Being more precise, the sentence just before that was: "Voglio dire che secondo me (this fact) è proprio il contrario (compared to what you said).

Comment: I am not sure about those 3 meanings, no more, no less, nor about the difference between 2. and 3. (where did you find them?), but if anything they apply to phrases of the form *fare* + another verb: *Lo faccio venire subito*, *Dobbiamo far riparare la lavatrice* etc., so that does not apply to the sentence about the *nonni*.

Comment: I just copy paste those definition from "Espresso 3" book from Alma publications (http://www.almaedizioni.it/en/informazioni/about-us/)

Comment: As an Italian mother tongue, I find it hard to conflate everyday use of *fare* with just those three meanings (and to discern the difference among 2. and 3.). As Gio correctly says, *fare* has countless fundamental meanings and idiomatic uses; even if your Italian is not enough to understand them, just have a look at the dictionary article he links or at [this one](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare2): in the latter, your three meanings are probably those explained in section 4.a, among many, many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you took those definitions from, but [FARE](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/F/fare.php) has many connotations and a wide idiomatic usage, it often translates the English "do and make".

In the exemple "***fare i nonni"*** the meaning is:

> - Agire, operare (come farebbe un nonno)

"fare i nonni" means to behave in a way that is or is supposed to be typical  of grandparents. So "fare i genitori" means to  behave like e parent would do. It refers to the role that grandparents have in current society where they often have to take care of their grandchildren because parents are unable, for a number of reasons,  to do so.

Hoepli

Comment: Thanks @Gio It was informative and precise. I just copy paste those definition from "Espresso 3" book from Alma publications (http://www.almaedizioni.it/en/informazioni/about-us/).